# Using Helvetica Neue Light - Html5 IOS app

Tags: ios, css, html, fonts

I'm having problems using helvetica-neue Light within a HTML5 IOS app.
I'm defining it in my CSS as -

```
font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light";
```

But it refuses to play ball - does it need to be defined differently?  "Helvetica Neue" works fine - so its very confusing.

According to IOS fonts it is available for IOS 5 and above (http://iosfonts.com/)

Any advice?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try

```
font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
font-weight: lighter;
```

Comment: You can also play around with multiples of 100 for font-weight.  'font-weight: 100;' may get you better results.

Comment: "lighter" means literally "lighter than what is defined in the parent". It is probably better to set a fixed font weight.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me now on iOS7. On Windows it just gives me Times.

```
    font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue Light, times;
```

Comment: Thats not a Windows font. On Windows 7/8 try using Segoe UI